# What if Package doesn't exist in newer version R

Tags: r

I did a lot of scripting on `R 3.3.2` , and then I figured out that I have to use version `3.3.3`

Problem is package `AnomalyDetection` doesn't exist on `3.3.3` (don't confuse with `anomalyDetection` (lower case 'a')).

Can I somehow use that package from older version? Isn't there some thing in R that makes older stuff work on newer version ?

Comment: Have you tried the installation instructions on the package's [github page](https://github.com/twitter/AnomalyDetection#how-to-get-started)?

Comment: @Marius, thanks , that worked. I thought only packages available in cran are suitable for installation.

Comment: @Sher CRAN packages are definitely a safer bet, since they have to go through a vetting process.  I've had lots of success with people's github-hosted packages, but often the documentation is much less developed.

Comment: CRAN doesn't generally allow case-conflicted packages to exist on CRAN so you likely installed that somewhere else besides CRAN but forgot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have both versions installed and use emacs with ESS, is pretty straightforward to open any of them by typing
    M-x R-3.3.2
or
    M-x R-3.3.3

So you could just go back to the older version for your specific purposes.

The alternative is, Do you really need to have R-3.3.3 for any specific reason? if no, just install back R-3.3.2 and use it.